# Make all fields of ManyToMany Model appear in form

Tags: python, django, forms, many-to-many

I am all new to coding, for my first project I decided to work with Django.

I am coding a web application that will permit a user to create specification sheets very easily, by completing a form that creates a pdf document (a specification sheet). My main model is "Fiches", from which I have m2m links to my other models that can contain 1 or several attributes each. All my codes are below.

model.py (not finished setting the parameters, just to have something to work with)

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.utils import timezone


    class Utilisateurs(models.Model):
        nom = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        prenom = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pays = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    class Calibres(models.Model):
        calibre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        tolerance = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    class Additifs(models.Model):
        denomination_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    class Ingredients(models.Model):
        denomination_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    class Formes(models.Model):
        denomination_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        Denomination_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        Denomination_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    class DimensionsProduit(models.Model):
        denomination_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        Valeur = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    class Conditionnements(models.Model):
        primSec_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        primSec_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        primSec_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        nature_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        nature_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        nature_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        compose_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        compose_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        compose_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        couleur_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        couleur_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        couleur_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    class DimensionsConditionnement(models.Model):
        Denomination_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        Denomination_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        Denomination_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        Valeur = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    class CriteresOrganoleptiques(models.Model):
        cru_Cuit_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        cru_Cuit_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        cru_Cuit_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        description_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        description_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        description_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    class CriteresPhysiques(models.Model):
        denomination_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        norme_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        norme_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        norme_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        tolerance_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        tolerance_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        tolerance_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    class CriteresMicrobiologiques(models.Model):
        denomination_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        norme = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    class CriteresChimiques(models.Model):
        denomination_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        norme = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    class CriteresNutritionnels(models.Model):
        denomination_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        valeur = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        unite = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    class Photos(models.Model):
        denomination_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        image = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    class AutresCaracteristiques(models.Model):
        denomination_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        denomination_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        detail_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        detail_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        detail_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    class Fiches(models.Model):
        utilisateurs = models.ForeignKey(Utilisateurs)
        type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        auteur = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        suivi_des_modifications = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        date_de_creation = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        famille_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        famille_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        famille_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        genre_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        genre_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        genre_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        espece_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        espece_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        espece_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        type_production_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        type_production_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        type_production_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pays_origine_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pays_origine_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pays_origine_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        zone_fao = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        technique_peche_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        technique_peche_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        technique_peche_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pays_transformation_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pays_transformation_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pays_transformation_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        numero_agrement = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        ville_transformation_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        ville_transformation_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        ville_transformation_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        process_transformation_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        process_transformation_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        process_transformation_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        type_congelation = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        taux_glazing = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        tolerance_taux_glazing = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        compensation_glazing_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        compensation_glazing_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        compensation_glazing_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        cru_cuit_FR = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        cru_cuit_EN = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        cru_cuit_ES = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        dluo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        poids_brut_par_carton = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        poids_net_par_carton = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        palletisation = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        calibres = models.ManyToManyField(Calibres)
        additifs = models.ManyToManyField(Additifs)
        ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredients)
        formes = models.ManyToManyField(Formes)
        dimensions_produit = models.ManyToManyField(DimensionsProduit)
        conditionnements = models.ManyToManyField(Conditionnements)
        dimensions_conditionnement = models.ManyToManyField(DimensionsConditionnement)
        criteres_organoleptiques = models.ManyToManyField(CriteresOrganoleptiques)
        criteres_physiques = models.ManyToManyField(CriteresPhysiques)
        criteres_microbiologiques = models.ManyToManyField(CriteresMicrobiologiques)
        criteres_chimiques = models.ManyToManyField(CriteresChimiques)
        criteres_nutritionnels = models.ManyToManyField(CriteresNutritionnels)
        photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photos)
        autres_caracteristiques = models.ManyToManyField(AutresCaracteristiques)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.code
```

forms.py

```
    from django.forms import ModelForm
    from . import models
    from django import forms

    class FichesForm(ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = models.Fiches
            fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from .forms import FichesForm
from django.utils import timezone
from FSE.convPDF import render_to_pdf
from .models import Fiches
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest


def fichepdffr(request, pk):

    nouvelle_fiche_pdf = get_object_or_404(Fiches, pk=pk)
    return render_to_pdf('fichepdf_fr.html', {'nouvelle_fiche_pdf':nouvelle_fiche_pdf})


def creaft(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FichesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("info valid")

            nouvelle_fiche = form.save(commit=False)
            nouvelle_fiche.save()
            form.save_m2m()

            return redirect('fichepdffr', pk=nouvelle_fiche.pk)
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()

    else:
        form = FichesForm()

    return render(
        request, "formulaire.html", {
            'form': form})
```

There are 2 things that, after hours of research and tests, I just can't find how to do:

1/ The ManyToMany links are automatically displayed with 1 ModelMultipleChoiceField in my form, but it's not the way I want them to appear. As a user will have to complete all the fields each time he creates a new document, I need all the attributs of all the model to appear in my form, including the one of the ManyToMany fields.

2/ Instead of a simple textbox, I'd like, for almost all fields of my form, to have a drop-down list that could also be incremented by the user (if the information is not in the drop down list, he could add it into the database by texting it in a textbox and it would be available for the next sheet creation in the drop down list). I've been reading about widget but I'm not sure about how to use them and if they are adapted to my situation.

I tried this on the forms.py (took "Calibres" as an example to try, it's one of the m2m) but it didn't work:

```
    class CalibresForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = models.Calibres
            fields = [
                'calibre',
                'tolerance', ]


    class FichesForm(ModelForm):
        calibres = CalibresForm(ModelForm)

        class Meta:
            model = models.Fiches
            fields = '__all__'
```

Sorry my code is in French, didn't have the reflex to code in English. Will have next time!

If you need any other information to understand my problem, don't hesitate to tell me :)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Wow, not exactly a user friendly form. Can you explain why are these M2M and not foreignKey? This would be a little raiser if foreign keys

Comment: Hello! m2m because for example with « calibres », each « Fiche » can have several « calibre » and each « calibre » will appear in several « Fiche ». Should be represented like that doesn’t it? And it will be separated into 3 forms: FR-EN-ES, so all of those fields won’t appear on the same form.

Comment: Ok, but you may want to implement multiple independent forms (wizard) so the user "creates fitche" -> "adds calibration" -> "adds calibration" or something like that. Anyway, don't have an answer to your question, so good luck

Comment: Yes that’s what I did on my first try, I created different forms to be displayed on the same final form. But then I got stuck with ma View, because I couldn’t figurate how to « group » all my forms into one « new_sheet ». This is not a very friendly form, my goal is indeed to make it as friendly as possible...

Comment: Not sure if I understand but you have one URL to create the fitche, and then you have different URLs for each associated form/view, but including the fitche ID in the URL. e.g. "/fitche/5/calibate/new" so you can get fitche 5 from the URL so you can automatically add the new calibration to it

Comment: With this method, for each m2m, I will have to click on « add a new calibre » for example, which will open a new page, right?

Comment: Yes, each would be and independent form and view

Comment: If there is no other option I will do that. But the ideal is to have everything on 1 form.

Comment: There is for sure, but I cannot imagine that adding a giant form is better than adding a wizard with multiple pages. If you want one form, search for nested forms but I don't have examples, so cannot answer

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!